# How do I access elevation values in a raster .tif?

Tags: ios, swift, raster, elevation, wgs84

If I have a GeoTiff file of elevation data in a WGS84 coordinate system, how do I access these pixel values in Swift?

The data is from the Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data 2010, specifically the file `30n090w_20101117_gmted_mea300.tif`.

Please let me know if you need more information to answer this question. Thanks so very much for your help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same. Surprisingly I'm not finding much info on how to do this on iOS